# About database keys

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, primary-key, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to figure out a way to design my SQL Azure database. There is a lot of information to be found about what your primary key should be (int versus guid) and advantages/disadvantages of both approaches, so I'm aware of the war going on there :)

But, I was thinking to apply best of both worlds by adding the following three columns to my tables:

- **InternalID**

  - IDENTITY of type int
  - defined as clustered index
  - used in joins
  - default value generated by database
  - unique in the table only
  - used internally only
  - can never change
- **ExternalId**

  - a Guid
  - default value generated by the client (or domain)
  - globally unique
  - used internally and externally.
  - can never change
- **UrlTitle**

  - a string
  - generated by the domain
  - unique in the table only
  - user-friendly representation of the entity used in public url's
  - can change (but preferably does not change)

By doing so it would have the performance of integer primary keys thanks to the InternalId, but still flexible enough because of the ExternalId.

I'm not a database specialist, far from it, so I would like to hear from you whether this is a feasible thing to do or maybe just plain ridiculous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing unusual about using several different keys in a table for different purposes. Make sure you enforce all the keys with uniqueness constraints and create appropriate indexes. Make sure your developers understand what each key is for and that they use them in a consistent way.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also the developer myself, so I have control over everything. I was just wondering if this approach is something that is considered as an 'accepted' design.